# Repair corrupted file list in reprepro

Tags: debian, reprepro

Seeing this message when `dput`'ing a package to my local reprepro instance:

```
...
Exporting indices...
Corrupted file list data for pool/main/q/qualys-cloud-agent/qualys-cloud-agent_2.6.0-88_all.deb
Corrupted file list data for pool/main/q/qualys-cloud-agent/qualys-cloud-agent_2.6.0-88_all.deb
Calculating packages to pull...
Installing (and possibly deleting) packages...
Exporting indices...
Deleting files no longer referenced..
```

I am running version 5.3.0 of reprepro on Debian buster.

How do I repair (or remove) the corrupted files?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem internal to the binary package (`*.deb`) itself, unrelated to `reprepro`.  (Almost) every binary package contains an `md5sums` file in its control component.  You can take a look at it wth:

```
ar -x qualys-cloud-agent_2.6.0-88_all.deb    # extracts {control,data}.tar.xz
tar -xf control.tar.xz                       # extracts control,md5sums
cat md5sums
```

The best solution is to release `qualys-cloud-agent_2.6.0-88.1` which is a simple rebuild of `2.6.0-88`.  Before you `dput` it, install it locally and verify the md5sums with `debsums` (from the `debsums` package).

```
dpkg -i qualys-cloud-agent_2.6.0-88.1_all.deb
debsums -c qualys-cloud-agent
```

If the check passes, you can `dput <your_repo> qualys-cloud-agent_2.6.0-88.1_all.changes`.

---

It's important to bump the version of the package because it'll ensure anyone who has installed this package from your repository gets the update.  If you really don't want to bump the version (maybe you are certain no one has used your repo); you could:

```
reprepro -Vb /path/to/repo remove buster qualys-cloud-agent
reprepro -Vb /path/to/repo include buster qualys-cloud-agent_2.6.0-88_all.changes
```

---

If the `debsums` fails, it would be useful to:

- know how you built your package (`dpkg-buildpackage`, `cpack`, `dpkg-deb`)
- see an extract from `/var/lib/dpkg/info/qualys-cloud-agent.md5sums` so we can look for any formatting problems
- know if you are using `reprepro includedeb` instead of `reprepro include`